# Selenium Test for file download

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, jboss6.x, jboss-arquillian

I would like to find out if it is nowadays possible to implement the "download testing" using Selenium. It would suffice to detect if the file download has started. 
It is important to say that the files are not static, so they are not accessible over specific URL. They are dynamically created and filled with data, depending on the user-provided input. 
I also cannot use the FirefoxProfile, because my automated web-tests use chrome driver and phantomjs. They also need to run under Hudson (here is of course used only phantomjs).
Application runs under JBoss Server so I am using Arquillian libraries.

Thank you

Comment: This won't be possible with PhantomJS. You should look into how you can run chrome with xvfb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible only for Firefox
thus special capabilities have to be configured

```
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv, image/png, application/octet-stream, text/plain") # File mine types
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)

firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/tmp")
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
```

But for any other browser I usually do a simple trick I get a link of file and than use f.e. requests lib and check file headers

```
import requests
r = requests.head("https://www.google.com.ua//images/srpr/logo11w.png")
assert r.status_code == 200
assert r.headers['content-type'] == 'image/png'
```

Comment: See another my solution, I hope this will help